# Как сделать свою команду в CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

я читал ответы на данный вопрос чуть-ли не на всех форумах, но так и не понял так её сделать. Говорят закинуть файл с расширением .os, .bat в папку с cmd, потом через GNUI (вроде правильно написал), но так и не понял. Буду благодарен если объясните как сделать свою команду в cmd.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я понял, для того чтобы сделать свою команду надо зайти в Систему (Панель Управления > Все элементы панели управления > Система > Дополнительные параметры системы > Переменные среды).

После этого в `Path` добавляете свою команду указывая путь. Примером будет переход из диска `C:` в диск `D:` введя одну команду. На диске `D:` создаем файл с названием `test.cmd` (Можно и другое название файла).

В `test.cmd` добавляем строки:
`@ECHO OFF`
`cd /D D:\`
после этого добавляем в `Path` свою команду и сохраняем. Введя команду `test`, консоль перейдёт из `C:` в `D:` с помощью одной команды, а не двумя.

P.S. Собственная команды в Консоли будет работать если введёте название файла.

P.S.S Можно вместо `.cmd` сделать расширение `.bat`